# Helm Chart - Camunda

Tags: kubernetes-helm, camunda, helm3

Good Morning.

I'm currently using an helmchart to deploy camunda inside an openshift namespace/cluster.

For your information, Camunda has a default process called "Invoice" and that process is responsible to create a default user called "demo".

I would like to avoid that user creation, so i was able to do it through docker with the following command:

```
docker run -d --name camunda -p 8080:8080 -v
/tmp/empty:/camunda/webapps/camunda-invoice
camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:latest
```

But now, my helm chart uses a custom "values.yaml" that calls the camunda image, and then issues a command to start it:

```
image:
  name: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform
  tag: run-latest
  command: ['./camunda.sh']
```

So is it possible to use the same behavior as docker command shown above, to empty the "webapps" directory after calling the camunda.sh?

I know that I can pass through the args: [  ] the argument "--webapps" but the issue is that it will remove the "tasklist" and "cockpit" that allows users to access the Camunda UI.

Thank you everyone.
Have a nice day!

**EDIT:**
While speaking with Camunda team, i just had the information that i can send the "--webapps --swaggerui --rest" arguments in order to start the application without having the default BPMN Process (Invoice).

So I'm currently try to use multiple arguments in my Helm Chart values.yaml like this:

```
image:
  name: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform
  tag: run-latest
  command: ['./camunda.sh']
  args: ["--webapps", "--rest", "--swaggerui"]
```

Unfortunately, it's not working this way. What am i doing wrong?
If I send just one argument like "--webapps" it reads the arguments and creates the container.
But if i send multiple arguments, like the example shown above, it just doesn't create the container.
Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: sorry, I had tried

Comment: No problem! I really appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The different start arguments for the Camunda 7 RUN distribution are documented here: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/#start-script-arguments
Here is a helm value file example using these parameters:

```
image:
  name: camunda/camunda-bpm-platform
  tag: run-latest
  command: ['./camunda.sh']
  args: ['--production','--webapps','--rest','--swaggerui']

extraEnvs:
- name: DB_VALIDATE_ON_BORROW
  value: "false"
```

Comment: Yes, after my team complete the debug of this camunda, we have found a huge bug related with this, and raised a PR for them...

Comment: Mind sharing a ticket no?